# Linux tool to monitor network performance

Tags: linux, networking, monitoring

I need some suggestions about monitoring various network statistics (like RTT, Packet loss, Jitter, packet retransmission) using linux command line. I have tried "SS" command but SS command gives stats for individual stream separately. Also, it doesn't give all these metrics. I need a tool/code which can give all these.

If there is no available such tool, is there any way I can get these metrics for the whole network?

Comment: did you try iperf? not sure if iptraf also have that metrics

Comment: You can use bcc/eBPF on your Linux server. These tools the best for network monitoring.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of such tools, e.g.

- [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org) -  a free application that enables you to catch and view the information going forward and backward on your system, giving the capacity to bore down and read the substance of every parcel – separated to meet your particular needs. It is generally used to investigate arrange issues and additionally to create and test programming. This open-source convention analyzer is generally acknowledged as the business standard, prevailing upon what’s coming to it’s of honors the years. Initially known as Ethereal, Wireshark highlights an easy to understand interface that can show information from many diverse conventions on all real system sorts.
- [iftop](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/iftop/) - this tool is a system monitor that allows us to know in real time all the processes that are running in our system and can manage them easily.
- [vnstat](https://humdi.net/vnstat/) - network monitor that is included, by default, in most Linux distributions. It allows us to obtain a real-time control of the traffic sent and received in a period of time, chosen by the user.
- [iptraf](http://iptraf.seul.org/) - console-based, real-time network monitoring utility for Linux
- [monitorix](https://www.monitorix.org) - a lightweight free utility that is designed to run and monitor system and network resources with as many Linux / Unix servers as possible
- [dstat](http://dag.wiee.rs/home-made/dstat/) - monitor is somewhat less known than the previous ones but also usually comes by default in many distributions.

and lots more...